# Holding self-defined objects as fields in other self-defined objects (c++)

Tags: c++

Im trying to implement a few data structures in c++, just to understand them better.

I have a question about the implementation. In general, if I have self-defined objects as fields of another objects, is it better to define a pointer to heap allocated memory of the object, or just a field of the object?

Consider the following example:

I tried to implement a basic stack as linked list, so one of the field (actually the only one) of the stack is a linked list, but Im not sure if this field should be a pointer to linked list (which is allocated in heap memory and initiallized in the constructor) or just a linked list.

Here's the implementation;

```
  #ifndef STACKASLINKEDLIST_H
#define STACKASLINKEDLIST_H
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T>
class StackAsLinkedList
{
    public:
    //|-------------------- Constructors --------------------
        StackAsLinkedList(){}
     //|-------------------- Methods --------------------
        void push(const T& toAdd){
            data.add(toAdd,0);
        }

        T& pop() {
            return data.remove(0);
        }

        T& peek() const{
            T tmp = pop();
            push(tmp);

            return tmp;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const {
            return data.isEmpty();
        }

    //|-------------------- Friend functions --------------------
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const StackAsLinkedList<T>& mStack){
                out<<mStack.data;
                return out;
        }
     //|-------------------- Destructors --------------------
        virtual ~StackAsLinkedList(){}

    protected:

    private:
        LinkedList<T> data;

};

#endif // STACKASLINKEDLIST_H
```

As I wrote it, I used as a filed just the LinkedList it self, Im not sure if its worst or better and if the implementation of the destructor works fine. Basically, in my implementation of LinkedList, anytime I push something to the stack a new Link appended to the LinkedList and this Link is allocated in the heap memory, so I do want the destructor of the stack to erase this memory.

I'd really appreciate a guidance/tips here. What is the best way to deal with the questions I asked? (Also I'd really appreciate any suugestions about improvements of the implemtation).

****In case it is important to the question, here is my implementation of LinkedList****

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "List.h"
#include "Link.h"



template <class T>
class LinkedList : public List<T>
{
    public:

    //|-------------------- Constructors --------------------
        LinkedList(): List<T>(),head(NULL) {}                                              //|Default constructor.

        LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other): List<T>() {                                 //|Copy constructor.
            head = other.head;
            Link<T>* otherCurr = other.head->next;
            Link<T>* thisCurr = head;

            while(otherCurr){
                thisCurr->next = new Link<T>(otherCurr->m_data);
                thisCurr = thisCurr->next;
                otherCurr = otherCurr->next;
                this->m_size++;
            }
        }
    //|-------------------- Methods --------------------
        bool isEmpty() const {
            return head==NULL;
        }

        int getSize() const {
            return this->m_size;
        }

        void add(T data,int index ){                                         //|Complexity time is O(n) because complexity time of getLink() is O(n).
                                                                             //|If we had a pointer to the position, this function complexity would be O(1).
            if(index > this->m_size){
                std::cout<<"Out Of Bounds"<<std::endl;
                return;
            }
            else if (index == this->m_size)
                addLast(data);

            else if (index == 0)
                addFirst(data);
            else{
                Link<T>* toAdd = new Link<T>(data);
                Link<T>* prevLink = getLink(index-1);
                Link<T>* indexLink = prevLink->next;
                prevLink->next = toAdd;
                toAdd->next = indexLink;
            }
            this->m_size++;
        }

        void set(int index, T data){

            if(index >= this->m_size){
                std::cout<<"Out Of Bounds"<<std::endl;
                return;
            }

            Link<T>* indexLink = getLink(index);
            indexLink->m_data = data;
        }


        T remove(int index){

            if(head== NULL){
                std::cout<<"The list is empty"<<std::endl;
                return NULL;
            }

            if(index > this->m_size-1){
                std::cout<<"Out Of Bounds"<<std::endl;
                return NULL;
            }

            if (index ==0 ){
                Link<T>* tmp = head;
                head = head->next;
                T toReturn = tmp->m_data;
                delete tmp;
                return toReturn;
            }

            Link<T>* prevLink = getLink(index-1);
            Link<T>* tmp = prevLink->next;
            prevLink->next = tmp->next;
            T toReturn = tmp->m_data;
            delete tmp;

            this->m_size--;
            return toReturn;
        }

    //|-------------------- Operator overload --------------------

        T operator[](int index) const {                                          //|Complexity time is O(n).
            Link<T>* relevantLink = getLink(index);

            if(relevantLink)
                return relevantLink->m_data;
            else
                return NULL;
        }

        bool operator==(const List<T>& other) const{                              //|Complexity time is O(n).
            if(! (typeid(other) == typeid(*this)))
                return false;

            if(this->m_size != other.getSize())
                return false;

            Link<T>* thisCurr = head;
            int i=0;

            while(thisCurr != NULL ){
                if(thisCurr->m_data != other[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
                thisCurr = thisCurr->next;
            }
            return true;
        }




    //|-------------------- Friend functions --------------------

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& mList){
            Link<T>* curr = mList.head;

            while(curr->next){
                out<< (*curr)<<" -> ";

                curr = curr->next;
            }
            out<<(*curr);
            return out;
        }

    //|-------------------- Destructors --------------------

        virtual ~LinkedList(){

            Link<T> *curr, *prev;
            curr= head;
            while(curr){
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                delete prev;
            }
        }

    private:

    //|-------------------- Private fields --------------------
        Link<T>* head;

    //|-------------------- Private Methods --------------------
        Link<T>* getLink(int index) const{                                           //|Complexity time is O(n).

            if(index >= this->m_size -1){
                std::cout<<"Out of bounds"<<std::endl;
                return NULL;
            }

            int counter =0;
            Link<T>* curr = head;

            while(counter < index){
                counter++;
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            return curr;
        }


        void addFirst(T data){
            Link<T>* toAdd = new Link<T>(data);

            if (head == NULL){
                head = toAdd;
                return;
            }

            toAdd->next = head;
            head = toAdd;
        }

        void addLast(T data){
            Link<T>* toAdd = new Link<T>(data);

            if (head == NULL){
                head = toAdd;
                return;
            }
            Link<T>* curr = head;
            while (curr->next != NULL)
                curr = curr->next;
            curr->next = toAdd;
        }

};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

Comment: in my opinion,  if your class need to manage array of self-defined object, care about expanding -> use pointer otherwise (array fixed length or manage single element ) use object is easier

Comment: @long.kl This is as I implemented LinkedList, it holds a pointer to the head link of hte list, and everytime I append a new link it is allocated in the momory, so If I'll use pointer to this linked list in the stack implementation Im not sure if it would give me anything because LinkedList alreadt holds pointers to heap memory allocated

Comment: yes, I knew about that, I mentioned about StackAsLinkedList class with `LinkedList<T> data;` member, I think it is object will easier than pointer. and if you have a list of linklist like`LinkedList<T> data[xyz]` with expanding requirement then pointer is better. like `LinkedList<T>* data;`

Comment: How should I imlement the destructor in this case? Recall that in my linkedlist implementation the links allocated in the heap memory

Comment: in case using object `LinkedList<T> data;` when StackAsLinkedList object is deleted -> its data also is deleted automatically by `~LinkedList()` . however with  `LinkedList<T> *data;`  in destructor of StackAsLinkedList you need `delete data or delete [] data` depend on what type of data

Comment: @long.kl I see. So in my case since im working with the object and not a pointer to the object, an empty destructor should be enough? virtual ~StackAsLinkedList(){}

Comment: yes, you can test it with some debug log, it's easy to test.